# Why did livedata builder not invoked when data inserted to room

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

im really new on AAC and repository.
I have made an app with MVVM and repository.

**Activity**

```
class UserTestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val userViewModel : UserViewModel by viewModel<UserViewModel>()

    private lateinit var  button : AppCompatButton



    private var count : Int =0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_test

        button = findViewById(R.id.testButton)

     
        val userObserver = Observer<MutableList<UserModel>> { newUserList ->

          
            Log.d("room-db-status", "size: "+newUserList.size)


        }

        userViewModel._user.observe(this, userObserver)



        button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {


            count++
            Toast.makeText(this, "updated: "+count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            userViewModel.insertUser(UserModel(
                uid = count.toString(),
                nickName = "Alexar",
                gender ="female",
                age = 22,
                birth ="19990901",
                mainResidence= "Seoul",
                subResidence = "???",
                tripWish = mutableListOf("!!!","!!?"),
                tripStyle = mutableListOf("!!!","!!?"),
                selfIntroduction = "hi -_-",
                uriList = mutableListOf("!!!","!!?"),
                geohash = "none",
                latitude = 37.455,
                longitude = 124.890,
                mannerScore = 4.5,
                premiumOrNot = false,
                knock = 0
            ))

        })
    }
}
```

this is **ViewModel**

```
class UserViewModel (

    private val userRepository : UserRepository): ViewModel() {



    val _user : LiveData<MutableList<UserModel>> = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {


        val data = userRepository.getAllUser()

      
        emit(data)
        

    }

    fun insertUser (userModel: UserModel) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            
            userRepository.insertUser(userModel)
        }
    }
}
```

**Repositoty**

```
interface UserRepository {

    suspend fun getAllUser () : MutableList<UserModel>
    suspend fun insertUser (userModel: UserModel)
}
```

**RepositoryImpl**

```
class UserRepositoryImpl (
    private val localDataSource : UserLocalDataSource,
    private val userMapper: UserMapper) :UserRepository{

    override suspend fun getAllUser() : MutableList<UserModel> {
        val userList : List<UserEntity> = localDataSource.getAllUser()
        var temp = mutableListOf<UserModel>()


        for (user in userList)
            temp.add(userMapper.entityToModel(user))

        return temp
    }


    override suspend fun insertUser(userModel: UserModel) {

        return localDataSource.insertUser(userMapper.modelToEntity(userModel))
    }
}
```

**UserLocalDataSource**

```
interface UserLocalDataSource {
    suspend fun getAllUser () : MutableList<UserEntity>
    suspend fun insertUser (userEntity: UserEntity) 
}
```

**UserLocalDataSourceImpl**

```
class UserLocalDataSourceImpl(

    private val appDatabase: AppDatabase) : UserLocalDataSource {



    override suspend fun getAllUser() : MutableList<UserEntity> {

        return appDatabase.userEntityDao().getAllUser()
    }

    override suspend fun insertUser(userEntity: UserEntity) {

        appDatabase.userEntityDao().insertUser(userEntity)
    }
}
```

**UserEntityDao**

```
interface UserEntityDAO {
    @Query ("SELECT * FROM user " )
    suspend fun getAllUser() : MutableList<UserEntity>

    @Query ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid = (:uid) ")
    suspend fun getUser(uid: String) :UserEntity

    @Insert (onConflict = REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertUser (user : UserEntity)

    @Query("DELETE FROM user WHERE uid = (:uid)")
    suspend fun delete(uid : String)     
}
```

there are also Mapper and Koin injection.
when trying to insert user data to room, it was successful. but
after that, **liveData Builder**

```
val _user : LiveData<MutableList<UserModel>> = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {


    val data = userRepository.getAllUser()


    emit(data)    
}
```

not invoked...

Of course, that builder is invoked only once when app started haha
who knows why??
I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on the `liveData` builder to be invoked when data is inserted/updated in DB. Please [refer to this doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) on how to work with `liveData` builder.

To achieve the case when an observer of `LiveData` is invoked when data is inserted/updated in DB, methods must return `LiveData` object in `UserEntityDao`:

```
interface UserEntityDAO {
    @Query ("SELECT * FROM user " )
    suspend fun getAllUser() : LiveData<List<UserEntity>>

    @Query ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid = (:uid) ")
    suspend fun getUser(uid: String) : LiveData<UserEntity>

    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but if i want to not use livedata in data layer(repository, datasource,...) only way to do is to use Flow??

Comment: Yes, to get updates from DB you can use either `LiveData` or `Flow`.